# How to clear query cache in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I tried this at root prompt but didnt help.

```
mysql> RESET QUERY CACHE;
```

IT showed

```
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

But history is still there.

How do I clear or delete history for queries that i typed.

Answer (score 41):

**Query cache** and **query history** are different things.

### Query Cache

MySql stores executed queries with their results in a [**query cache**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache.html), so it can quickly respond when the same query requested (*cache hit*).
Run [`RESET QUERY CACHE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/query-cache-status-and-maintenance.html) or [`FLUSH TABLES`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/flush.html) to clear query cache.

### Command History File

MySql stores commands executed from its own shell in a [**history file**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-history-file.html). It is located under your home directory (Unix): `~/.mysql_history`. Remove this file to clear history up to now **(from shell)**:

```
rm -rf ~/.mysql_history
```

If you want to disable history completely, create the history file as a symlink to `/dev/null` **(from shell)**:

```
ln -s /dev/null $HOME/.mysql_history
```

Answer (score 7):

Mysql runs its own shell. You can delete this history by deleting the file that the history is read from, which is stored in `~/.mysql_history`

Comment: Is this about clearing the history of mysql or the query-cache?
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache.html

Comment: The question is ambiguous

Answer (score 3):

If, in fact, we are answering how to clear the "history" (not the cache), and we're talking about a 'nix platform... there is another important history file to delete potentially.  I.e. `/root/.mysql_history`.

When accessing MariaDB (i.e. a MySQL fork if you were not aware), it's typical to launch it as `sudo`.  In which which case your client input history is written to `/root...` instead of your home directory.

If you want to clear all recent input on BOTH the mysql client and the bash terminal for security purposes, try executing the following:

```
rm -rf ~/.mysql_history
sudo rm -rf /root/.mysql_history
history -cw
clear
```

I've used that successfully on CentOS and Debian running MySQL or MariaDB.

Answer (score 0):

I would be cautios with rm with recursive option, I've been always warned to think twice before using -r

Why just don't use

```
rm ~/.mysql_history
```